# How can I filter by file type in an IExplorerBrowser in Windows 7 Libraries?

Tags: windows-7, libraries

I've created an instance of IExplorerBrowser in my code to create a custom I/O view in one of my dialogs. I've implemented the IServiceProvider and ICommDlgBrowser interfaces in my host class. I use the IExplorerBrowser::BrowseToIDList method to fill the view.

I would like to filter the file types displayed (ex. only PNG files). If I call BrowseToIDList with *FOLDERID_Pictures* (i.e. "My Pictures") I can use the ICommDlgBrowser::IncludeObject method or IFolderFilter::ShouldShow to restrict which files I allow to be displayed. However, if I browse to the Picture Library on Windows 7 (*FOLDERID_PicturesLibrary*), neither ICommDlgBrowser::IncludeObject nor IFolderFilter::ShouldShow are ever called.

Is there some limitation to filtering files in libraries on Win7 that I'm unaware of? Perhaps I'm missing an interface or maybe I've specified the wrong flag somewhere.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This took me quite a while](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "Note that the client does not receive a call to `ICommDlgBrowser::IncludeObject` if a folder filter has been set on the browser by a call to `IFolderFilterSite::SetFilter`."

Answer (score 2):

I've had a chance to research this further, including asking a few questions to some Microsoft developers. It would appear, unfortunately, that filtering does not work with query backed views (i.e. Libraries).

An alternative to my approach would be to use the Common Item Dialog with application added controls (via IFileDialogCustomize).

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776913(VS.85).aspx)

In my specific case, I'm unable to use a Common Item Dialog, but I thought it might be worthwhile to post this information here for future reference.

If in the future I find any way to filter an IExplorerBrowser control, I'll post that back here too.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue myself.

Yet I have investigated it a little bit further. `IExplorerBrowser` creates (on my Windows 7 x64 machine) window of `ExplorerBrowserControl` class. Which itself creates a window of `DUIViewWndClassName` class. And the very same window (`DUIViewWndClassName`) is used as a control by dialog created by `IFileOpenDialog`. Even window procedures are same so there is no subclassing (but I haven't checked each and every subwindow of that control).

And file dialogs are able to filter by file type even in the library folders. So I guess the `IExplorerBrowser` (or the control it uses) does allow that only Microsoft does not share knowledge how to do that. Or if it does then its somewhat hidden knowledge.

But I got it with `IFolderFilterSite` (interface supported by `IExplorerBrowser` from `CLSID_ExplorerBrowser`). `IFolderFilter::ShouldShow` isn't called in such cases for library folders. I wasn't able to get `ICommDlgBrowser::IncludeObject` called (even if I didn't set any `IFolderFilter`).

---

EDIT: I managed to get `ICommDlgBrowser::IncludeObject` called. Somehow I forgot that I have to provide `ICommDlgBrowser` through `IServiceProvider::QueryService` rather than through `IUnknown::QueryInterface`. But still `ICommDlgBrowser::IncludeObject` is not called for library folders.

Comment: I have done few more (still unsuccessful) experiments and asked the question on MSDN Forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsuidevelopment/thread/252a9c82-617c-4126-8347-56dcedb4342f.

Answer (score -1):

I tried using IShellFolderViewDual3->FilterView().
But it's search results.
Thank you.

IShellView *pShellView;
IDispatch *pDSFV;
IShellFolderViewDual3 *pSFVD3;

m_pExplorerBrowser->GetCurrentView(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pShellView));
pShellView->GetItemObject(SVGIO_BACKGROUND, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pDSFV));
pDSFV->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pSFVD3));
pSFVD3->FilterView(bstrVal);

Comment: The purpose of this posting is not clear. Please add some explanation. Are you saying this is a solution to the question? Or are you asking for help on a similar problem?